# How to avoid borg to cross filesystem boundaries

Tags: filesystems, partition, backup, borgbackup

I am looking for a way to backup one filesystem by borg and I do
not want it to following mount points to another partitions.
A mechanism like the flag **`-x`**  in rsync.

I feel that I missed something from the documentation

--udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`borg create`](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html) supports an `-x` flag which limits the backup to a single file system.

Comment: Very important because it is not documented.  Tharvermore, in  --help it shown like a short for **--export=**.   Thanks Stephen (+1)

Comment: It’s documented in the page I linked to, which is part of the official Borg documentation...

Comment: I'm surprised that that is not the default